# How to reload datatable by using new url and some parameters without reinitialize it

Tags: ajax, datatables

I know I can make ajax request on datatable using ajax.url like [this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()) :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "/mylink"
} );

...

table.ajax.url( 'newData.json' ).load();
```

But how can I pass data as parameters to url using the same syntax?
I try `table.ajax.url( 'mylink' ).data(myData).load();` . Obsviouly it is not solution.

I do not want to destroy and reinitialize the datatable in order to use :

```
...
"ajax" : {
        "url" : "mylink",
        "data" : myData
 }
 ...
```

What do I do? What is the syntax using existing initialized table (here js var table)?
thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your DataTables `ajax` section, instead of using the *object* form of the `data` option, you can use the *function* form. This allows you to dynamically pass in your request data for each new ajax call.

So, instead of this:

```
"data" : myData
```

It would be this:

```
"data": function () {
  return myData;
}
```

And, as you already note, you can use the `ajax.url()` call to specify the new URL:

```
table.ajax.url( 'newData.json' ).load();
```

---

**Warning**: This assumes you are *not* using server-side processing, as this will overwrite the server-side request data which is auto-generated by DataTables. If you are using server-side processing, then you have to merge your custom data into the pre-existing request data.

The [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) shows an example for that, using jQuery `extend`:

```
"data": function ( d ) {
  return $.extend( {}, d, {
    "extra_search": $('#extra').val()
  } );
}
```

You don't *need* to use `$.extend`. You just need to be careful that you do not overwrite the request data generated by Datatables.

Another way to handle this is to simply append data to the data structure represented by `d` in `"data": function ( d )`:

```
"data": function ( d ) {
  d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
}
```

---

**Update** with a more detailed example

Here is a full example, which you can copy into a html file and run for yourself, if you wish. It uses data from a dummy JSON provider, just for testing.

The HTML, showing the table and a button. The button is how I tested the ability to call a new URL and pass new request parameters to that new URL:

```
<div style="margin: 20px;">
    <button id="button_one" type="button">Resubmit</button>
    <br><br>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
</div>
```

Here is the related script containing the DataTable definition and a function which calls the new URL (with new request parameters):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  // ajax for initial table creation:
  var requestUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  var requestData = { "name": "Abel", "location": "here" };

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
      method: "GET",
      url: requestUrl,
      "data": function ( ) {
        return requestData;
      },
      dataSrc: "",  
    },
    "columns": [
      { "title": "User ID", "data": "userId" },
      { "title": "ID", "data": "id" },
      { "title": "Title", "data": "title" }
    ]
            
  } );
  
  $("#button_one").click(function() {
    // subsequent ajax call, with button click:
    requestUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    requestData = { "name": "Charlie", "location": "there" };
    table.ajax.url( requestUrl ).load();
  });
  
} );

</script>
```

The key points in this example are:

1. There are 2 different URLs. The first one is used when DataTables is created. The second one is used when the button is clicked.
2. There are 2 different sets of request data, for the two URLs.

Using this approach, you can repeatedly call `table.ajax.url( requestUrl ).load()` with different URLs and different sets of request data, without needing to destroy the DataTable.

---

**Handling Form Data**

Here is a simple HTML form:

```html
<form id="filter-form">
    City:<input type="text" id="city" name="city">
    Country:<input type="text" id="country" name="country">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For testing, I have the following JavaScript which captures the contents of the form into an array:

```
var form_data = [];

$( "#filter-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  form_data = $( this ).serializeArray();
  table.ajax.url( url ).load();
});
```

The end result is data like this in the `form_data` variable:

```
[
  {
    "name": "city",
    "value": "Berlin"
  },
  {
    "name": "country",
    "value": "Germany"
  }
]
```

Now I can merge that data into the automatically created server-side request data. This is where I can choose to use the `$.extend()` function I mentioned above:

```
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: { 
      method: "POST",
      url: url, // from a variable
      data: function( d ) {
        return $.extend( {}, d, { "my_extra_data": form_data } );
      }
    },
    ... //whatever else is in your DataTable definition...
  });
```

This function results in request data like the following:

```
{
    "draw": "2",
    "columns[0][data]": "id",
    "columns[0][name]": "",
      ...
    "start": "0",
    "length": "10",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
    "my_extra_data[0][name]": "city",
    "my_extra_data[0][value]": "Berlin",
    "my_extra_data[1][name]": "country",
    "my_extra_data[1][value]": "Germany"
}
```

You can see your `my_extra_data` values are included along with the server-side auto-generated request data. And all of this gets sent to the server as part of your request.

If you are using `POST` then it's in the request body.

If you are using `GET`, then it's the same data - but added to the URL as a query string.

In both cases, it's converted to the standard string representation used by form data.

It's then up to the server-side code to access this data in the usual way.

NOTE: You may have expected your URL-encoded form data to be provided as this:

```
...&city=Berlin&country=Germany
```

But instead it is provided as arrays of name/value pairs:

```
&my_extra_data%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=Berlin&my_extra_data%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=country&my_extra_data%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=Germany
```

So, there is extra server-side work needed to parse this data.

If you want to convert your form data *directly* into a JavaScript object like this:

```
{ "city": "Berlin", "country", "Germany" }
```

then take a look at the answers to this question:

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: I want to use table.ajax.url( 'newData.json' ).load(); with url and parameters (data I must pass). I am afraid your answer currently is not helping me, or I don't understand your solution

Comment: I have provided a more detailed example, showing the approach. Let me know if that clarifies my answer - or not. And, let me know if I have misunderstood what you are trying to do, of course.

Comment: Thanks @andrewjames for your explanation. In my case it is loaded from serverside, and when I apply table.ajax.url('myurl'+"?filter_author="+filter_author).load() it works. the first initialization uses only url "myurl". But the issue is I need to send more params. and these are from form. so it will be painful to add each param to the url using & and ?. This is why I am asking a simply method to do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "_it is loaded from serverside_"? Does that mean your DataTable is using `serverSide: true`? Or does it mean something else? (You don't need to build a string using `?` and `&` - you can use the approach I have provided - but with some changes to account for the data being in a form, and for `serverSide`, if you are using that).

Comment: Yes I mean serverside:true.` but with some changes to account for the data being in a form, and for serverSide` so what are these changes I need to make for form data? when I check your solution, the ajax request on button click does not have submitted data.

Comment: I added some more notes relating to form data and server-side processing.

Comment: Thanks so much @andrewjames for being so patient and kind.