# Datables serverSide ajax POST 'error': "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"

Tags: javascript, python, datatables

now i got some error when i try to get data and display on the datatables which using serverSide.

following to my code below i have get my data by using ajax POST method because i want to send some data that need to use to filter in my database, and this is my code.

Javascript

```
report_table = $('#report_table').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "load_report_table",
                "type": "POST",
                "data":{
                    'region_id': function() { return $('#select_reg').val() },
                }
            },
});
```

Python

```
from datatables import ColumnDT, DataTables
from flask import request
@app.route('/load_report_table', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def load_report_table(): 
    reg_id = request.form['region_id']
    columns = [
        ColumnDT(Battery_Log.time),
        ColumnDT(Battery.serial_number),
        ColumnDT(Battery_Log.usage),

    ]
    query = db.session.query().select_from(Battery, Battery_Log)\
            .filter(Battery.reg_id == reg_id, Battery_Log.battery_id == Battery.id)

    params = request.args.to_dict()
    rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)

    return rowTable.output_result()
```

but when i print `rowTable.output_result()` it got the error like this.

```
{'draw': '1', 'recordsTotal': '14733', 'recordsFiltered': '14733', 'error': "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"}
```

For now i guess the error that cause by using `POST` method because when i have change my code to call only url and not post any data to the route function it work normally, the code is show below.

```
report_table = $('#report_table').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "deferRender": true,
            "ajax": "load_report_table"
});
```

So are there anyway to fix that i can POST my data to my route function and return the data to show on the datatables.

Comment: Your approach (using a function for the `data` option) is correct - but the syntax is incorrect. You can see a couple of examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243388/how-to-reload-datatable-by-using-new-url-and-some-parameters-without-reinitializ/66244738#66244738). Everything needs to be placed inside the function (including `'region_id'`). Also, bear in mind the warning in the same link about not overwriting `serverSide` response data.

Comment: @andrewjames Thank for response, i have try with this `"data":function () { return {'region_id': function() { return $('#select_reg').val() }};` and this `"data":function (d) { return $.extend( {}, d,{'region_id': function() { return $('#select_reg').val() }});` but it still got the same error T-T

Comment: Right - because those are not valid syntaxes, either. You have a function inside your JavaScript object `{ }`. You don't need that. You just need the value of `$('#select_reg').val()`. Why wrap that in a function?

Comment: @andrewjames Because i want it to be current value when i reload the datatable and now i have change it to `$('#select_reg').val()` or even i set it to static value like 1 but it still not working, for now i wonder may be `sqlalchemy-datatables`(Backend) that not working with POST method because i also try with not send any data to flask but it still not working anyway.

Comment: Sorry if my point was not clear. You only need the one function `"data": function () { ... }`. Inside that function you can write whatever (valid!) JavaScript you need to build the `{ ... }` object you need. You do not need a _second_ function to do that. Because you are using a function for your `data` option, it will be re-evaluated every time you re-execute the DataTable's ajax call (for example by using [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - for example, as a JS Fiddle.