# DataTable features not working for Return ajax records

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a very basic HTML table, The data is from the database. I have now set up a selector and as soon I Select any of the options then an AJAX request to get specific data for a specifically selected location. (To make it easier my query just looks for LocationId=1001 as an example). I now want to return the data and update the DataTable, but unfortunately, the data is returned, and it shows in the table but other DataTable features are not working.
Like pagination, Search, and the number of records.

**PHP page code**

```
$LocId = '1001';
$sql_Select = "SELECT tbl_employee.EmpId,tbl_employee.FirstName,tbl_employee.LastName,tbl_section.SectionNameEn,tbl_section.SectionNameAr FROM `tbl_employee`,`tbl_section` WHERE tbl_employee.SecId=tbl_section.SecId and tbl_employee.Status='Active' and LocId = '$LocId'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_Select);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
          }
        $msg = ["data" => $rows];
        echo json_encode($msg);
```

**Function for Ajax call and return records to view in DataTable**

```
function GetEmployee(){
        var LocId = $('#location').val();

        $('#basic-datatablee').DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "serverMethod": "post",
            "ajax": {
                "url": "ajaxpages/get_employee.php",
                "data": {LocId:LocId}
            },
            "columns": [
                    {"data": "EmpId"},
                    {"data": "FirstName"},
                    {"data": "LastName"},
                    {"data": "SectionNameEn"},
                    {"data": "SectionNameAr"},
                ],
            language: {
                searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
                sSearch: '',
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: The DataTable is using `"serverSide": true`. This means that all pagination, sorting and filtering will no longer be handled automatically by DataTables. Instead [the server becomes responsible](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for those actions. The first question to ask is: Why do you need to use `"serverSide": true`?

Comment: @andrewJames I'm using it because getting records using ajax call with parameter if there is any other way please explain with code I already mention my php page code and datatable script.

Comment: You don't need to use that option just because you have an Ajax data source - even with a parameter. Look at the description I linked to in my first comment. That describes why the option exists. Basically, it allows you to handle large data volumes.

Comment: Instead, look at what you can do with the [`ajax.url().load()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()) API call. That allows you to dynamically change your URL (e.g. by changing a parameter it uses) in response to a client-side action - such as a user choosing something from a selector. Example: [How to reload datatable by using new url and some parameters without reinitialize it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66243388/12567365). Does that meet your needs? If not, can you edit your question to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove

```
"serverSide": true,
"servermethod": "post",
```

Add this ajax call type

```
"type": "POST",
```

This will solve the problem